# How to make a upswipe full screen component in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface, expo

I have a scrollview type of a component where there will be a lot of listings in the list. Now what I have seen is that when you scroll down in that list, it basically takes the full screen. How can I make it and if there is already a component or property for it?

I want something just like uber lite:
[image] Now in this you have a little light rounded bar above search. In that scroll thing if you scroll down, it will go full screen and if you scroll back up, well, back to normal. I really loved this but I have no idea what this is called or how to make it work.

PS 1: PS: I thought of catching the scroll event and etc but it be great if there is faster and efficient way.
PS 2: This question might be a bad one but I want this.

Comment: you can use react-native-reanimated and animate it to take full height on scroll event. reanimated basically handles everything, you just need to set up the animations. https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/useAnimatedScrollHandler/#example

Comment: Ohk and what about back to normal?

Comment: Just the same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNw8lPdD4H4 you can look at this example, i guess it's similar to what you want. But it uses version 1. Version 2 is much simpler but there is no usage example of what you want